# Parse and validate Asterisk dialplan before commiting

Tags: asterisk

I recently made a number of changes to my Asterisk dialplan and would like to validate these changes before I commit. I am thinking more from a "write code" -> "compile" -> "debug" approach.

I am very new to Asterisk and am trying to build my dialplan slowly but the server is already in use (by the spouse) so I'd like to minimize interruptions as much as possible.

If I can at-least verify that the code is correct, I can then debug in Asterisk as calls are taking place.

Comment: After all how did you get around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently functionality like you're looking for in Asterisk.  The best solution that comes to mind would be to setup a testing server and check all your code in there.  The other solution would be to run your dialplan tests in seperate "contexts".  This would keep your testing dialplan code/logic seperate from that of your spouse.