# Determine which user initiated call in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I had the following code in my `extensions.conf` file:

```
[local]
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,1,Set(CALLERID(name)=${OUTGOING_NAME})
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=${OUTGOING_NUMBER})
```

Now I want to change this code to set the CallerID and number based on the user/extension that is making the call. In fact I have four(4) users/extensions in my `sip.conf` and only one of them (the one I use for business) is supposed to send a different caller id/number.

Everything is in the same context (for simplicity) since all lines need to be able to pick up an incoming call. The only difference is when `line1` needs to make a call, it has to send a different caller id/number and use a different provider.

This is what I have so far:

```
[local]
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,1,Set(line=${SIP_HEADER(From)})
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Verbose(line variable is <${line}>)
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(CALLERID(name)=${IF($[ ${line} = line1 ]?${COMPANY_NAME}:${FAMILY_NAME})})
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=${IF($[ ${line} = line1 ]?${COMPANY_NUMBER}:${FAMILY_NUMBER})})
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,n,Dial(${IF($[ ${line} = line1]?SIP/${EXTEN}@${COMPANY_PROVIDER}:SIP/${EXTEN}@${FAMILY_PROVIDER})})
```

I really don't know if this is correct and [I'm afraid to commit these changes to my `extensions.conf` before validating](https://serverfault.com/questions/449446/parse-and-validate-asterisk-dialplan-before-commiting).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a GUI such a FreePBX on this Asterisk box?

Comment: No, I'm using a terminal to make all these changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I found out that I can get the information I need from `${CALLERID(num)}`.

So, this is what I did:

```
[local]
exten => _NXXNXXXXXX,1,Set(line=${CALLERID(num)})
same => n,Verbose(line variable is <${line}>)
same => n,GotoIf($["${line}" = "line1"]?business-out,${EXTEN},1:family-out,${EXTEN},1)

[business-out]
...

[family-out]
...
```

Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 1):

As per the [VoIP Info Wiki](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+sip.conf) you can specify the callerid information on SIP extensions on a per extension basis like this:

```
callerid="Tuomas Tammisalo" <1000>
```

**UPDATE:**
You can access the [CDR variables](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Detailed+Variable+List)  on the call has started.  "${CDR(src)}" would give you the source extension of the call.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful response. However, I still need the functionality to detect the caller because, I send different caller Ids depending on which destination it is. I have several inbound numbers for different regions.

Comment: Does ${CDR(src)} give you what you're looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I was able to get it from `${CALLERID(num)}`